# Reading JSON from Yahoo Finance

Tags: javascript, json, yahoo-finance

I have an issue regarding the data from a JSON.

Link to example JSON: [Example for Apple](https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown)

I am using this code:

```
function yFinance(symbol) {
    const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(symbol) 
              + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail,incomeStatementHistory,'
              + 'balanceSheetHistory,defaultKeyStatistics,financialData,calendarEvents,'
              + 'recommendationTrend,upgradeDowngradeHistory,majorHoldersBreakdown'
    ;
  
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  
    if (responseCode === 200) {
        const quote = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        const paths = [
            'summaryDetail/dividendRate/raw',
            'summaryDetail/payoutRatio/raw'
        ];

        return getMatchingValues(getPath(quote, 'quoteSummary/result/0'), paths);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1; 
    }
}

function getPath( obj, path ) {
  if (!path || !obj) {
    return null;
  }
  const parts = path.split('/');
  const currentPath = parts[0];
  const nextPath = parts.slice(1).join('/');
  const currentObj = obj[currentPath];
  
  // final path, exit here
  if (nextPath.length === 0) {
    return currentObj;
  }
  
  if (Array.isArray( currentObj )) {
    // does an element exit at the next level
    if ( currentObj[parts[1]] ) {
      // will continue reading for 1 element
      return getPath( currentObj, nextPath );
    }
    // return all the subpaths, skip the ones that are falsy
    return currentObj.map( item => getPath( item, nextPath ) ).filter( v => v );
  }
  // get the next part of the object
  return getPath( currentObj, nextPath );
}


function getMatchingValues( obj, paths ) {
  return paths.flatMap( path => getPath( obj, path ));
}
```

The code is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809076/requesting-and-reading-json-from-yahoo-finance-with-a-generic-function)

As I am not an expert with JSON, I have this issue:

Why can I get the data for ones but for others the results are null?

I do not grasp the diference.

I tried to change, in the code, "dividendRate/raw" by "enterpriseValue/raw" or "ebitda/raw" but they return null instead of a specific number.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK found the solution.

For "enterpriseValue":

- instead of 'summaryDetail/dividendRate/raw'
- is 'defaultKeyStatistics/dividendRate/raw'

For "ebitda/raw":

- instead of 'summaryDetail/ebitda/raw'
- is 'financialData/ebitda/raw'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).